# Label Is Not Defined

Tags: python, tkinter

What is wrong here please help. It's writing **lbl1 is not defined**. I defined it already is the order is wrong how can I repair it? Everyday im having a problem like this could you help mee???

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Calculator 2")

window.geometry("400x400")




def func1():
    lbl1 = tkinter.Label(window, text="1")
    lbl1.pack()

def func2():
    lbl2 = tkinter.Label(window, text="+")
    lbl2.pack()
def func3():
    lbl3 = tkinter.Label(window, text="2")
    lbl3.pack()



btn1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="1", command=func1)
btn2 = tkinter.Button(window, text="+", command=func2)
btn3 = tkinter.Button(window, text="2", command=func3)
btn1.pack()
btn2.pack()
btn3.pack()

def funclst():
    if lbl1 == "1" and  lbl2 == "+" and lbl3 == "2":
        rstt = tkinter.Label(window, text=(int(lbl1) + int(lbl3)))
        rstt.pack()

lst = tkinter.Button(window, text="Calculate", command=funclst)
lst.pack()







window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include the **complete** error traceback, don't just cite approximately the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You create the labels inside functions. When the function ends the names assigned to the labels are garbage collected. Later when you try to access the variables in the `if` statement they are not defined in the global scope.

Also; the `if` statements checks if `lbl1 == "1"` which will not work as `lbl1` is the reference to the label and not to the text inside the label. The text can be accessed through `lbl1['text']` or `lbl1.cget("text")`